# dtrace on linux does not always remove userland probes at program exit -- why?

Tags: c++, c, linux, dtrace

(See end of this post if you want to see how I installed dtrace - for now I'll assume you already have it installed)

I made a custom probe with no problems at all by following these steps:

**A**. Create thing.d with my probe definition

```
provider thing {
    probe test();
};
```

**B.** Create a simple main.cpp

```
#include "thing.h"

int main()
{
    // Fire my probe
    THING_TEST();

    // Something to prevent immediate exit
    for(;;)
        sleep(1); 

    // Bye
    return 0;
}
```

**C.** Compile (but don't link) main.cpp.  Note how you must define _DTRACE_VERSION or else your probes will be commented out in thing.h.

```
g++ -D _DTRACE_VERSION -c main.cpp -o main.o
```

**D.** Build the probe object file (note that you must include main.o as part of this)

```
dtrace -G -s thing.d -o thing.o main.o
```

**E.** Link it all up

```
g++ main.o thing.o -o thing
```

Here's the problem:  Run the app, and terminate with CTRL-C (obviously the app won't stop by itself because of the infinite loop...).

In fact, do this a few times.

Now, from a superuser terminal:

```
# dtrace -l | grep thing
322991 thing28217            thing                              main test
322992 thing28403            thing                              main test
322994 thing28636            thing                              main test
```

These guys are just hanging around...  It's like they never got de-registered or something.
I've run "ps" to see if there are any procs with those pids (28217, 28403, 28636) and nope, nothing there.

INTERESTINGLY, if I remove the infinite loop from main.cpp (the sleep() loop) and just let the app immediately exit, then the probes are properly removed.  So it seems like the issue has to do with CTRL-C being detected inside of sleep() - perhaps some kind of atexit() handler isn't being called?

Here's my system info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux beavis 3.5.0-26-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 8 23:18:20 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
```

---

**DTRACE INSTALLATION**

I am not using the default dtrace that comes with Ubuntu, but rather the dtrace4linux stuff which I installed like this:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/60940/how-do-i-install-dtrace
```

**NOTE**: I am using the latest version from Paul Fox's site:

```
ftp://crisp.dyndns-server.com/pub/release/website/dtrace/dtrace-20130317.tar.bz2
```

Comment: BTW - I tried the same thing on OS X and the problem did NOT occur.  Please keep in mind that on OS X you do not need to create a probe object file, and you also do not need to -D _DTRACE_VERSION when compiling.  Just compile and link in one step:  g++ main.cpp -o thing